# how to access and subscribe data from angular in memory api having data structure like this

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Suppose, I am having array of object like this and I want to display data from the following below data structure in angular material table.

This is my service code `inmemorydata.service.ts`:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
const element_data = [
            {
                a : {
                    first: 'xyz',
                    second: 'uvw',
                    third: 'pqr',
                   },
              b :{
                    slow: '35',
                    medium: '60',
                    fast: '120',
                    },
             c:[
                    {name: 'donald',price:677,unit:12,paid:270, value:324, gain:554},
                    {name: 'xing',price:235,unit:85,paid:5375, value:6175, gain:2375},
                    {name: 'son', price:159,unit:45,paid:715, value:6360, gain:785}

                ]
            }
        ];
        return {element_data};
}}
```

and this is my html file `app.component.html`:

```
<mat-table  #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

              <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                    The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

              <!-- Fund name Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fund name </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.c[0].name}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- Sell price Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sell price </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.c[0].price}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- Unit Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="unit">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Unit </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.c[0].unit}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- You paid Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="paid">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> You paid </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.c[0].paid}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- Current value -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Current Value </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.c[0].value}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- Gain -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="gain">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Gain </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.c[0].gain}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>

              <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
              <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

and , here is my typescript file `app.component.ts`:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
      displayedColumns = ['name', 'price', 'unit', 'paid', 'value', 'gain'];
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

      constructor( private tableService: TableService ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.tableService.getTable().subscribe(
          data => {  this.dataSource.data = data }

        )
      }
}
```

So how can I iterate the values so that I can get the mocked data displayed in tabular form. Or how can I subscribe the published data.

---

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
f
d
df
f
f
f
f
f
f a f g h h j j k k k k k  l
f
f
f
f

Comment: right now i am getting only first row in that table

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `[datasource]` to be `datasource.c` and just use `{{element.<<key>>}}` in each row, then you will be fine. When you declare `let element`, that `element` is an object in your array (e.g. first element will be `{name: 'donald',price:677,unit:12,paid:270, value:324, gain:554}`).

You are only getting the first row because you're using `element.c[0]` in every row.

Comment: is there any other way to fetch only value of array c in component.ts file

Comment: @SHYAMAKANTSHARAN Take a look at this Stackblitz that I editted: https://angular2-material-table-ylabfp.stackblitz.io